# Weeks between two dates in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to calculate the number of weeks that a customer has been a customer. The goal is to compare this to the distinct number of weeks the customer has made a purchase to determine what % of weeks the customer made a purchase.

With timestamp `customer.created_at` what is the best way to find the number of weeks a customer has been a customer? Said differently, the difference in weeks between the current week and the week in which the customer signed up.

Calendar weeks starting Monday to be apples-to-apples with distinct calendar weeks a customer has made a purchase.

Comment: What day are you using as the start of the week?

Comment: Calendar weeks, or 7-day blocks? Which calendar - Monday first or Saturday first? ("weeks" are hard, you have to define them very clearly)

Comment: Good point, should have made this clear. Calendar weeks starting Monday. The goal is to make it apples-to-apples with the distinct weeks the customer has placed an order (which is calendar weeks starting Monday).

Comment: Saturday first??? What is this madness?!?!

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(days FROM (now() - customer.created_at)) / 7)::int;
```

First find the difference between current time and customer's created_at time stamp.
Then you tell Postgres to give you the difference in days and then you can divide that by 7 and round it to an integer. Note that if you do not want an integer, you can cast appropriately.

Comment: Great, thanks. This is close. Per above comments, I am looking for calendar weeks starting Monday. So if a customer signed up on Friday, week of 6/2/14, the query should return 1 for weeks_a_customer, even though the customer signed up today.

Comment: only works as long as the interval is below one month!

Answer (score 10):

AFAIK this should work in all cases

-Your calendar week starts on Monday 
-Both dates start at least from 05.01.1970 (Monday)

Postgres:

```
SELECT
(
extract(epoch from date_trunc('week',now()::date))
-
extract(epoch from date_trunc('week','2019-12-20'::date))
)
/604800
```

(where 604800 is the number of seconds in a week)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select (CURRENT_DATE - customer.created_at)/7
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. The question is asking for difference in calendar weeks, where week starts on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I used. Works.

```
SELECT
  (
    (
      (
        CURRENT_DATE::DATE - (EXTRACT('dow' FROM CURRENT_DATE::DATE) * INTERVAL '1 day')
      )::DATE -
      (
        customers.created_at::DATE - (EXTRACT('dow' FROM customers.created_at::DATE) * INTERVAL '1 day')
      )::DATE
    ) / 7
  ) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have that to get the calendar weeks

```
select to_char(i::date, 'IYYYIW') AS mdate from generate_series('2017-01-01', current_date, '1 week'::interval) i;
```

and to count

```
select count(to_char(i::date, 'IYYYIW')) from generate_series('2017-01-01', current_date, '1 week'::interval) i;
```

and you can replace the date with customer date

Answer (score 0):

@zach's answer is (perhaps) valid, however, it is hard to follow.

I found these two procedures that abstract equivalent logic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION first_of_week(date) returns date AS $$
  SELECT ($1::date-(extract('dow' FROM $1::date)*interval '1 day'))::date;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weeks_in_range(date,date) returns int AS $$
  SELECT ((first_of_week($2)-first_of_week($1))/7)+1
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE STRICT;
```

Source:

https://gist.github.com/tkellen/2003309#file-gistfile1-sql-L17-L23

Example:

```
SELECT weeks_in_range('1900-01-01',CURRENT_DATE);
 weeks_in_range 
----------------
           5854
(1 row)
```

Note, that the above example assumes Sunday to be the start of the week. Alternatively, if you want Monday as a start of the week, then use `date_trunc`, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weeks_in_range(date,date) returns int AS $$
  SELECT (((EXTRACT(DAY FROM (date_trunc('week', $2::date) - date_trunc('week', $1::date))))/7)+1)::int
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE STRICT;
```

`first_of_week` is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select ((in_FinishDate - in_StartDate) / 7 +
     case
         when ((date_part('dow', in_StartDate) = 6) and (date_part('dow', in_FinishDate) != 6)) or
              ((date_part('dow', in_FinishDate) = 0) and (date_part('dow', in_StartDate) != 0)) then 1
         when (date_part('dow', in_StartDate) = 5) and (date_part('dow', in_FinishDate) in (1, 2, 3, 4)) then 1
         when (date_part('dow', in_StartDate) = 4) and (date_part('dow', in_FinishDate) in (1, 2, 3)) then 1
         when (date_part('dow', in_StartDate) = 3) and (date_part('dow', in_FinishDate) in (1, 2)) then 1
         when (date_part('dow', in_StartDate) = 2) and (date_part('dow', in_FinishDate) in (1)) then 1
         else 0
         end)::int;
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuttal to @maleckicoa. The following demonstrates why one cannot user a constant of 52 weeks in a year for difference between dates spanning the Dec-to-Jan time frame.  
Instead of hard coding Dec 2019 - Jan 2020 (which works just fine) the following generates the annual dates 29-Dec to 4-Jan for the period 2019 through 2030. In most the maleckicoa's algorithum works, but ...

```
with recursive annual_dates(dec_dt, jan_dt) as 
     ( select make_date(2019,12,29), make_date(2020,01,04)
       union all 
       select (dec_dt+interval '1 year')::date, (jan_dt+interval '1 year')::date
         from annual_dates 
        where extract(isoyear from dec_dt)::integer < 2030        
     )  --select * from annual_dates; 

select dec_dt, jan_dt, 
       extract( isoyear from jan_dt)*52 + extract( week from jan_dt)
       -
       extract( isoyear from dec_dt)*52 - extract( week from dec_dt) "Weeks Between" 
  from annual_dates;       


with recursive annual_dates(dec_dt, jan_dt) as 
     ( select make_date(2019,12,29), make_date(2020,01,04)
       union all 
       select (dec_dt+interval '1 year')::date, (jan_dt+interval '1 year')::date
         from annual_dates 
        where extract(isoyear from dec_dt)::integer < 2030        
     )  --select * from annual_dates; 
select 'Week for ' || dec_dt || ' is ' || extract( week from dec_dt) || ' And '
       'Week for ' || jan_dt || ' is ' || extract( week from jan_dt) || ' Giving Difference of '
        || extract( isoyear from jan_dt)*52 + extract( week from jan_dt)
           -
          extract( isoyear from dec_dt)*52 - extract( week from dec_dt) || ' Weeks Between' 
  from annual_dates;
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work in Postgres for most cases (Week starts with Monday, the year has 52 weeks)

Example for year end 2019:

```
select 
extract( isoyear from '2020-01-04'::date)*52 + extract( week from '2020-01-04'::date)
-
extract( isoyear from '2019-12-29'::date)*52 - extract( week from '2019-12-29'::date)
```

Comment: This is a old post long settled I guess, but your answer is recent. Unfortunately, it's incorrect. It fails because the contention that years have 52 weeks is incorrect. Some have 53, and 29-Dec of some years are the 1st week of the following year. BTW, Jan-4 is always in the 1st week of the year; it's the ISO8601 definition of it.

Comment: Hi @Belayer, thanks for the coment! I pointed out it works for most cases (when the year has 52 weeks). How would you write this code (in postgres) so that it works in ALL cases and for all years/weeks? Much appreciated.

Comment: I've posted a demonstration showing results for the next  from 2019-2030. Dates routines always need testing over a fairly long period, They are just NOT very well behaved.  Works in all cases. I'll have to think about that a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Belayer!, I see your point. I have posted another solution that should work in all cases. Please review it if possible.